# C# For Visual Studio Code - Acting as if not installed

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I had installed the C# extension for Visual Studio Code for Microsoft. Everything was working fine for the longest time with getting intellisense, using OmniSharp commands. I installed another extension call C# prettier, to change how it would auto format the document. I did not like it so I uninstalled.

Ever since I have not been able to execute any of the OmniSharp Commands.

I went into the extension settings and mapped OmniSharp: Restart to a keyboard shortcut and this is the output I see:

"command o.restart not found"

The OmniSharp commands are also missing from the command palette.

[command palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1hP2.png)

I have verified there is no issues with my .NET sdk paths:
6.0.411 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.304 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

This is what I have tried so far:

1)Restarting VS Code.

2)Uninstalling Extension - Restarting VS Code - Reinstalling Exension.

3)Rebooting my machine.

Output of Command - Developer: Show Running Extensions:

I can see that the C# extension is in this list and has a startup activation of 30ms.[Developer: Show Running Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvD14.png)

**Update**
I reverted back to version 1.26.0 and now it is working. It looks like the newer versions were not able to find the path to the .net sdk. Even after I explicitly added it in the extension settings.

Comment: Providing CODE instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Comment: 1) show and describe in words what you see in the window that opens when you run `Developer: Show Running Extensions` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). 2) Then open the Output Panel and look for any related looking log messages that might indicate what's going on.